# Request to AWS SES API failed. Reason: Error executing "SendRawEmail" in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I am trying to send emails with AWS SES. I followed the Laravel official doc and configured the application. but when I tried to send an email I got the following error. I was using `ses` as `MAIL_MAILER` at this time.

> Request to AWS SES API failed. Reason: Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://email.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com.

I assigned `AmazonSESFullAccess` and `AmazonSNSFullAccess` permissions directly to my IAM user. I was using `aws/aws-sdk-php` package with my Laravel application but while trying to solve the issue I tried with `aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel` package too. But the error remains the same.

Then I generated an SMTP access credential and used it for sending emails. This time it worked.

I want to use the SES config for mail sending with Laravel. It would be really helpful if you please help me to find the issue and solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/faq.html#what-do-i-do-about-a-curl-ssl-certificate-error):

1. Download the latest certificate from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Open the `php.ini` file and add the following lines. Here `C:\wamp64\php\ssl\cacert.pem` is the path of the certificate file. I was using `wamp` if you are using `xampp` or something similar, this path might be different.

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\php\ssl\cacert.pem"

[openssl]
openssl.cafile = "C:\wamp64\php\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

3. Restart web server/apache/fpm php service
4. Test the mail again, it should work perfectly.

Be sure that you are updating the right `php.ini`.